# What would be the correct Regular Expression to extract ID from href in below html for jmeter regular expression

Tags: regex, jmeter

My HTML code is:

`<a class="view-details-ul-none" href="javascript:printCertificate('11673191')">`

I try this expression: `href="javascript:printCertificate(\)|\(.*?)">`
it return me the ID but along id number it return brackets and comma too, like below image:

[image]

When I pass this regular expression to next request as parameter my url become wrong and http send 500 http error code. because url looks like this:

`GET https://Domain/path/completionCertificate.pdf?Id=('11673191')`

Could anyone please help me in this would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not just use `href="javascript:printCertificate\('(.*?)'\)">`

Comment: Thank you so much Burhan Khalid for helping me. After putting your suggested regex my case executed successfully. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go for the following regular expression:

```
<a class="view-details-ul-none" href="javascript:printCertificate\('(\d+)'\)">
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Regex Demo]

Remember to escape the following characters outside character classes:

```
.^$*+?()[{\|
```

and these inside the character classes:

```
^-]\
```

References:

- [What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) With JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)